# How can we prevent ngModel from overriding custom css in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend, ecmascript-2016

The NgModel directive in Angular tries to override the custom CSS that I have provided in my code .
For instance, the structure is :

```
<div class=wallpaper>
<mat-toolbar> 
...
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-card>
.
.
.
</mat-card>
</div>
```

As soon as in the form input, I add [(ngModel)] in place of [(value)]. It overwrites the CSS of the mat-toolbar. Hence, the background-color of mat-toolbar changes from black to transparent.

Code Snippet :

```
 <mat-form-field>    
      <mat-select placeholder="Status" **[(***ngModel***)]**="incident.status"  >    
      <mat-option style="background-color:grey">-- Select --</mat-option>    
      <mat-option style="background-color: green" value="1">Available</mat-option>    
      <mat-option style="background-color: orange" value="2">Reduced</mat-option>    
      <mat-option style="background-color: red" value="3">Unavailable</mat-option>    
      </mat-select>    
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add ***name*** which is a template reference variable in the form where [(ngModel)] is declared. This variable is then used for accessing the DOM properties of the element.

The [(ngModel)]sets a two way binding on the elements value and assigns that to a variable.

Template variables help you use data from one part of a template in another part of the template. With template variables, you can perform tasks such as respond to user input or finely tune your application's forms.

**Corrected Code Snippet :**

```
<mat-form-field>    
     <mat-select placeholder="Status" [(value)]="status"  [(ngModel)]="incident.status" name="status">    
         <mat-option style="background-color:grey">-- Select --</mat-option>    
         <mat-option style="background-color: green" value="1">Available</mat-option>    
         <mat-option style="background-color: orange" value="2">Reduced</mat-option>    
         <mat-option style="background-color: red" value="3">Unavailable</mat-option>    
     </mat-select>    
</mat-form-field>
```